# Is the 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1/*' API still active?

Tags: delicious-api

So url tagging website is back running on it's original URL of [del.icio.us](https://del.icio.us) . I have a java client which attempts to call the original REST API via the URL in the title but all calls fail. I'm wondering can someone confirm what the correct API URL now is, if any. Documentation seems scarce.

Comment: The following URL was working as recently as mid-March `http://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/recent?count=10` but now returns a `404`. I think they've taken it down very recently.